# UISwipegesturerecognizer to change ImageView positions on the view controller?

Tags: objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm an Objective-C beginner and I've found similar answers on stackoverflow to my question, but even after trying all of the tips/advice I'm still lost.

I have an IBOutlet UIImageView, and I want it to be so that if the user swipes up or down on this Image, then the position of various images on the view controller change.

I'm very green with the UISwipegesturerecognizer coding, so please explain in a way a beginner would understand. Thank you very much in advance!!!

> UPDATE:

@Axeva, I used the following code, and there are no caution warnings or errors. However, it isn't executing properly on my simulator. Here is my code :

```
interface math0 (){
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp;}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(swipedScreenUp:)];
[swipeUp setNumberOfTouchesRequired: 1];
[swipeUp setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
[one addGestureRecognizer: swipeUp];
[swipeUp setEnabled: NO];
}

- (void)swipedScreenUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeGesture {
// Sampling to see if it works
instructions.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IT WORKED!"];
}
```

In my .h file, I declared ***- (void)swipedScreenUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeUp;**. On my storyboard, I set my image (named one) so that it was accessibility and user interaction enabled. 
 I've also tried with [swipeUp setEnabled: YES]; in my viewDidLoad file.

> Can you or anyone tell me where the error is? Thank you!!

Comment: Show your code. What exactly is the problem? What have you tried? Maybe you just need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to YES.

Comment: thanks for responding, in my header file I simply declared: IBOutlet UIImageView *swipedObjectOne; I know I need to activate user interaction with "imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;", but I'm not sure where to put this bit of code

Comment: I also feel that I need to use:    <code>- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
        swipedObjectOne.center = CGPointRect(desired location x, desired location y);  
    } 

} </code>

Comment: Also, I'm having difficulty formatting my code for my comments and posts here, I apologize everyone

Comment: Definitely comment out `[swipeUp setEnabled: NO];`  That was a mistake leftover from a copy and paste of one of my projects.  Also make sure the outlets are set properly for the `one` UIImageView.

Comment: @Axeva I've commented out that line of code. As for the inline `one` UIImageView, I just declared it on the .h file. Is there any additional code I need to add to it? I also set it's accessibility on through storyboard

Comment: Did you attach the image view in your storyboard to the property in your class?  See: [A Beginner’s Guide to Storyboard Object Connections & Delegates](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection)

Comment: Yes I did. I'm not sure what it can be, but I'll keep searching for answers in books. Thanks for the guide and I"ll look through that first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@interface YourViewController () {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftToRightGesture;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    swipeLeftToRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(swipedScreenRight:)];
    [swipeLeftToRightGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired: 1];
    [swipeLeftToRightGesture setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer: swipeLeftToRightGesture];
}

- (void)swipedScreenRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeGesture {
    // Move your image views as desired
}
```

You can adjust this basic code to do exactly what you wish.  (different swipe directions; etc.)

Comment: Thank you, that's extraordinarily helpful. Can I ask, how would I make it so that the app user would have to swipe ON a particular Image View? To clarify, if he/she swipes on a certain "A" Image, then "A" action occurs, but he/she has the option to swipe on "B" Image and "B" action will occur... Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it Kevin – above where it says `[[self view] addGestureRecognizer: swipeLeftToRightGesture];`, change that `[self view]` to be the name of the "A" Image and the gesture will work on that image.  Create a different one for the "B" image to handle swipes on that, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope one day I can help others like you've helped me. Best regards,

Comment: if you have time could you please read my updated question? Thank you sir